# -train function does not subset the dataset

Tags: r, subset

Using the train function, I am trying to create two sub-datasets. My original dataset has 2215 observations (UCI_CC_cleaned). Using the code below, I could create the training dataset (UCI.train) with 575 observations, but the test dataset does not have the correct dimensions.  I am expecting 2215-575 observations, but it contains 2214 observations.

```
   train <- UCI_CC_cleaned$random >0.75
          UCI.train <- UCI_CC_cleaned[train, ]
  UCI.test <- UCI_CC_cleaned[-train, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical vector in `train`, try to use `!` to reverse the sign.

```
train <- UCI_CC_cleaned$random > 0.75
UCI.train <- UCI_CC_cleaned[train, ]
UCI.test <- UCI_CC_cleaned[!train, ]
```

You can use `which` to use `-` :

```
train <- which(UCI_CC_cleaned$random >0.75)
UCI.train <- UCI_CC_cleaned[train, ]
UCI.test <- UCI_CC_cleaned[-train, ]
```